# PHP: Logical Operator: Why does (5 || 3) return 1?

Tags: php, logical-operators

While building a small Feedback-Solution where people can give a number of stars (between 0 and 5), I noticed that all user submitted ratings are stored with just 1 star.

I tried it myself by submitting 5 stars and the backend still shows 1 star.

So I looked into the code and this is the piece that causes the trouble:

```
$feedback->rating = ($wire->input->post->rating || 1);
```

Actually the `||` operator isn't doing what I suspected it to do.
In fact it just returns 1 every time (unless both hand sides are $false).

Check my example code below:

```
$example1 = ($true || 5);
$example2 = ($false || 5);
$example3 = ($false || $false);
$example4 = (5 || 0);
echo $example1."\n";
echo $example2."\n";
echo $example3."\n";
echo $example4."\n";
```

Also I made a paste here: https://eval.in/514978.

What I'm assuming is, PHP tries to convert the statements to an integer (either 0 or 1) depending on the given elements, is that true?

I'm used to use the `||` operator in JavaScript a lot where I can just type

```
var i = myFunction() || "default";
```

This will check if myFunction() returns a bool-ish value and if not just uses the right hand side value (rather than turning everything into an int).

Comment: Why don't you just google [Logical operators PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)? This knowledge and knowledge about [type casting in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) would be the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` is the **or** operator in PHP and it evaluates to either `true` or `false`. If you want the binary or operator you should use `|` instead.

Since everything not equall zero is treated like `true` it makes sense that all of the evalations give `true`, which as integer becomes `1`.

You can see more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

> Example   ----- Name  -----Result
>   $a || $b  ------- Or ---------TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

Comment: Yep that's what I was expecting. Accepting this in the next few minutes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference to PHP `||` handling as opposed to other languages.

In PHP `5 || 7` will always return true; the `||` operator will always return a boolean.

`5 || 7 = true;`

In other languages like javascript. `5 || 7` will return 5 and `7 || 1` will return 7; the `||` operator will return the parameter that was evaluated true (or the last parameter);

```
5 || 7 = 5;
7 || 1 = 7;
0 || 7 || 1 = 7;
0 || 0 = 0;
```

In PHP you can achieve the same by using a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

`$result = $int ? $int : 1;`

if the $int is implicitly true, $result will be $int, otherwise $result will be 1;

Or since PHP 5.3:

`$result = $int ?: 1;`

Comment: How will 7 or 1 return 1 in js?

Comment: I seem to have messed up, with changing The format I guess

Answer (score 2):

```
$feedback->rating = ($wire->input->post->rating || 1);
```

Come on, It is returning `TRUE` which you see as 1

Try this

```
echo TRUE;    //1
```

What you are looking for is a **[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**.

```
$feedback->rating = $wire->input->post->rating ?: 1;
                                               ^^
```

This gives you that value if it is set, otherwise gives you an actual 1.

Comment: sure. But it returns 1 even if the right hand side isn't 1 but 5. I was just questioning the or operator (because I'm used to the javascript-or-operator which works in a different way)

Comment: `5 || 1` is `TRUE`, not 1 nor 5. And when you echo TRUE in PHP you get 1

Comment: I did not notice the change to ternary operators before in that you could leave out the part between ? and :
+1